# Integer-String Parser

Tags: parsing, integer, byte, parseint

I am parsing an XML document, and when I try to save the String (data) that I am reading as an **Integer**, I found an exception.

```
Integer.parseInt(data)
```

I also tried changing the atribute type to **Byte** and trying on another way but it did not work.

```
{Byte.parseByte(data)}
```

More precisely, I am doing,

```
{message.setType(Integer.parseInt(data));}
```

I have also tried with *valueOf* and *intValue* and it did not work either.

messageType was both times (int or byte).

While I am parsing the XML, I print out data and it exactly has the value and lenght that I am expecting. (value:9, length:1)

Comment: What exception do you get? What library are you using to parse the XML data? What is  `message`?

Comment: Also, we can help you in a more timely manner if you provide a complete example which illustrates the issue you have encountered. See [this article](http://www.sscce.org) for tips.